# How to find partial and infinite sum of $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{m}\frac{1}{(na+b)^k}$ (if $a,b$ - constants)?

Tags: summation

How can I find partial sum of
$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{m}\frac{1}{na+b}$$
and infinite sum of
$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(na+b)^k}$$
if $k>1$ and $a,b$ - constants?

I sure it simple, but really have no ideas.

Comment: I dont's think there there is a closed formula for this.

Comment: A closed form for the latter, would be a closed form for the Riemann Zeta, when $a=1$ and $b=0$; thus I think it could be rather difficult

Comment: As Joe already said the second sum is related to the Euler-Riemann Zeta function. Euler derived a closed form solution for $2k$ in which $k \in \mathbb{Z}- \{0\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the finite sums
$$S_k=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{m}\frac{1}{(na+b)^k}=\frac {(-1)^k}
{(k-1)!\, a^k}\left(\psi ^{(k-1)}\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)-\psi ^{(k-1)}\left(\frac{b}{a}+m+1\right) \right)$$
For the infinite sums (with $k>1)$, this simplifies to 
$$T_k=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(na+b)^k}=\frac {(-1)^k}
{(k-1)!\, a^k}\,\psi ^{(k-1)}\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)$$ where appear the polygamma functions.

Answer (score 1):

The closest form you will find ( I think ) is

> $$
> \sum_{n=0}^{m}\frac{1}{an+b}=\frac{1}{a}\left(\psi\left(m+\frac{a+b}{a}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)\right)
> $$

where $\psi$ is the digamma function given by
$$
\psi\left(z\right)=\frac{\Gamma'\left(z\right)}{\Gamma\left(z\right)}
$$