# How to find the sum $1+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{10}-\frac{1}{11}+\cdots =\ ?$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let $\phi(x)=\begin{cases}0, & 0\lt x\lt 1\\ 1, & 1\lt x\lt3 \end{cases}$

We have that the Fourier cosine series is given by $$\phi(x)=\begin{cases}0, & 0\lt x\lt1\\ \frac{4}{3}+\displaystyle\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{-2\sin\frac{m\pi}{3}}{m\pi}\cos\frac{m\pi x}{3}, & 1\lt x\lt3 \end{cases}$$

Put $x=0$ to find the sum

$\displaystyle 1+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{10}-\frac{1}{11}+\cdots$

I tried the following

$$\phi(0)=\frac{4}{3}+\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{-2\sin\frac{m\pi}{3}}{m\pi}\\=\frac43-2\frac{\sin\frac{\pi}{3}}{\pi}-\frac{\sin\frac{2\pi}{3}}{\pi}-2\frac{\sin\pi}{3\pi}-\frac{\sin\frac{4\pi}{3}}{2\pi}-\cdots\\=\frac{4}{3}-\frac{\sqrt3}{\pi}-\frac{\sqrt3}{2\pi}-0+\frac{\sqrt3}{4\pi}\dots=\frac{4}{3}-\frac{\sqrt3}{\pi}(1+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}\dots)=\ ? $$

And I'm stuck here,

What can I do here?

I greatly appreciate any assistance you may provide.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that $\phi(x)$ is in fact an even periodic function with period 6?

Comment: @user hmm I don't know, I think a proof is required to verify what you say. How would that help to find the sum?

Comment: I was going to check that the Fourier series is correct (as it have appeared - not quite).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2643731/514787

Comment: @user514787 your sequence is not the same as mine, I have a $-\frac{1}{4}$ and you have $\frac{1}{4}$

Comment: @Al t. it just a special case, try to read whole answer.

Comment: @user so the correct Fourier series $\phi$ is like the one you have in your answer, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key observation, which will be exploited below in computing the series
$$
S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sigma_n}{n},
$$
where $\sigma_n$ is repeating sequence of $(1,1,0,-1,-1,0)$, is that
$$
\sigma_n=\frac{2}{\sqrt3}\sin\frac{\pi n}{3}.
$$
It follows:
$$
S=\frac{2}{\sqrt3}S',\text{ with } S'=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin\frac{\pi n}{3}}{n}.\tag{1}
$$
It appears to be simpler to compute directly $S'$. Two approaches to perform this are given below.

---

The first way, suggested in question, exploits the Fourier series of the even periodic function:
$$
\phi(x)=\begin{cases}
0& -1<x<1\\
1& -3<x<-1\text{ or } 1<x<3 
\end{cases};\quad\phi(x+6)=\phi(x),
$$
which is:
$$
\phi(x)=\frac{2}{3}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2\sin\frac{\pi n}{3}}{\pi n}\cos\frac{\pi n x}{3}.\tag{2}
$$
Substituting in (2) $x=0$ one obtains:
$$
0=\phi(0)=\frac{2}{3}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2\sin\frac{\pi n}{3}}{\pi n}=
\frac{2}{3}-\frac{2}{\pi}S'\Rightarrow S'=\frac{\pi}{3}.
$$

---

The second way is more direct as it does not rely on a foreknowledge of an appropriate function for Fourier series. Observe that for $|x|<1$:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty{x^n\sin\frac{\pi n}{3}}=\frac{1}{2i}\left(\frac{1}{1-xe^{\frac{\pi i}{3}}}-\frac{1}{1-xe^{-\frac{\pi i}{3}}}\right)
=\frac{x\sin\frac{\pi}{3}}{1-2x\cos\frac{\pi}{3}+x^2}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\frac{x}{1-x+x^2}.
$$

Thus, 
$$
S'=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin\frac{\pi n}{3}}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sin\frac{\pi n}{3}\int_0^1 x^{n-1}dx=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\int_0^1\frac{dx}{1-x+x^2}=\frac{\pi}{3}.
$$

---

Finally the sum in question is computed using (1) as:
$$
S=\frac{2}{\sqrt3}S'=\frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt3}.
$$

Comment: How did you find that $S=\displaystyle \frac{2}{\sqrt3}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin\frac{\pi n}{3}}{n}$ ?

Comment: @Alt. As $\sin\frac{\pi n}{3}$ is a repeating sequence of $0,\frac{\sqrt3}{2},\frac{\sqrt3}{2},0,-\frac{\sqrt3}{2},-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$ the expression $\frac{2}{\sqrt3}\sin\frac{\pi n}{3}$ takes on the values 0,1,1,0,-1,-1, i.e. exactly the values which enter the sum in question.

Comment: The sum in question $\displaystyle 1+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{10}-\frac{1}{11}+\cdots$ takes vaules 0,1,1,0,-1,-1,... ? How do you know?

Comment: wait, I think you mean this $\phi(x)=\frac{2}{3}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2\sin\frac{\pi n}{3}}{\pi n}\cos\frac{\pi n x}{3}$ as sum in question ?

Comment: @Alt. Look at the _numerators_ of the series you have written Do you see the pattern? Imagine that the series contains also 0/3, 0/6 and so on...

Comment: yes, it's $0,\sqrt3,\sqrt3,0,-\sqrt3,-\sqrt3$. Ok

Comment: @Alt. Exactly. And it is the same as $\sqrt3(0,1,1,0,-1,-1)$.

Comment: oh I see, thanks. Looking again at your answer I think there's a small typo in $\phi(0)=0$ ? Forget about it, there's no typo. There's a question, why did you change to the interval -1<x<1 in the definition of $\phi(x)$?

Comment: @Alt. I did it to ensure that $\phi(x)$ is an even function of $x$. Otherwise $\sin$-terms were needed in the Fourier series.

Comment: $?$ What do you mean with 'Otherwise sin-terms were needed in the Fourier series' ?

Comment: @Alt. If a function is not even, its Fourier series necessary contains $\sin$ terms. And the series in your question contained only $\cos$-terms, contrary to given definition of $\phi(x)$ (neither you did mention that the function is periodic). This was the reason of my question in the comment to your question.

Comment: oh ok I think I am understanding, so I think the original definition of $\phi(x)$ given in the exercise is wrong because $\cos(x)$ is always even, but the interval $(0,1)$ didn't satisfy it

Comment: It  should be $4/3$ and not $2/3$ as you have in your definition of $\phi(x).$ $A_0=(2/3)\int_1^3(1)cos(0)dx=4/3$

Comment: $F [f (x)]=A_0\color {red}{/2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n\cos\frac {2\pi n}{T}x+B_n \sin\frac {2\pi n}{T}x$.

Comment: :) right, I forgot about it..

Answer (score 6):

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1963693), it is shown that
$$
\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{z+k}=\pi\csc(\pi z)
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\left(\frac1{3k+1}+\frac1{3k+2}\right)
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\left(\frac1{3k+1}-\frac1{-3(k+1)+1}\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac{(-1)^k}{3k+1}+\frac{(-1)^{-k-1}}{3(-k-1)+1}\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{3k+1}\\
&=\frac13\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k+\frac13}\\
&=\frac\pi3\csc\left(\frac\pi3\right)\\[6pt]
&=\frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt3}
\end{align}
$$