# How to interpret the word 'find' in an exercise?

Tags: optimization, soft-question, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, duality-theorems

If an exercise says:

Let $X=\{x:x\ge0\}$. Find the dual function of the minimization problem $c^tx$ s.t. $Ax=b,x\ge0$.

And If I write:

The dual function is given by $\max\theta$, where $\theta =\inf\{f(x)+u^tg(x):x\in X\}$, where $f(x)=c^tx$ and $g(x)=Ax-b$, then is my answer

incorrect?

or correct?

or how is it?

As you can see, the task is to **find**, but it does not says *find explicitly* nor *find implicity.*

And I did find it (implicitly)

Comment: Well, if you can solve the exercise in one line then generally, you did not do enough, I assume. Can $\theta$ be computed concretly ? If so, I guess you are intended to do so.

Comment: In which book did you find this excercise?

Comment: If I asked students to find the solution set of the equation $x^2-2x+7=0$, I would not give any credit for “The solution set is $\{x\in\mathbb C : x^2-2x+7=0\}$,” and I would not feel too bad about it, even though the statement is true.

Comment: @SteveKass but the answer it's actually correct. :) you didn't write _find explicitly_

Comment: @user441848 Define "explicitly."

Comment: @ClementC. Taking the example Steve provided, the _explicit_ solution would be something like $x=4,-1$ (no real answer just an example)

Comment: So... You know "explicit" when you see it? The appropriate definition is context-dependent, as is that of "closed form." Want to go down that rabbit hole?

Comment: @Suzet or maybe I am not intented to do so, it does not says _find explicitly_

Comment: @FrankMoses Nonlinear Programming by Bazaraa. Why?

Comment: @user441848 In the question you posted here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2759901/how-to-find-the-sum-1-frac12-frac14-frac15-frac17-frac1 "how to find the sum [...]", you did not write "explicitly", but I am sure you would not have been satisfied with the answer "Well, this sum equals $1+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{10}-\frac{1}{11}+\cdots$".

Comment: @Suzet haha no of course not, I'd be upset, but that clearly does not mean that your answer "Well, this sum equals $1+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{10}-\frac{1}{11}+\cdots"$ is incorrect.